# How to autoscroll with percentage or pixels in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, uiscrollview, scrollbar

I have this code to auto scroll to a specific id.
My question is if there is the possibility of autoscroll not to an id but to a certain part of the page with pixels or percentage.
Thanks for the help.

This is the code I have

```
        scrollTop: jQuery("#id").offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: scrollTop also accepts an numeric value where you can simply specify a pixel value. For a percantage value take the height of the viewport and figure out how much x% are and put in the result as a pixel value

Comment: @empiric Could you give me a code example please? Thanks

Comment: You can use window.scrollBy(x-coord, y-coord);
check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation of [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) it expects a numeric value. The same applies for the usage within `animate`.

So for a set pixel value just omit the function of getting the offset of an element and put in the value directly. Same goes for the percentage value but with a bit of math involved.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $(".pixel").on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 200 //set a numeric value to scroll a set amount of pixel
      }, 800, function(){
      });
  });
    $(".percent").on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var percent = 90;
    var percentPixel = windowHeight * (percent / 100); // calculate the amount of pixel off a percentage

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: percentPixel
      }, 800, function(){
      });
  });
});
```

```css
body, html, .main {
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="pixel" href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll 200px</a>
<a class="percent" href="#section2">Click Me to Smooth Scroll 90%</a>

<div class="main">
  <section></section>
</div>

<div class="main" id="section2">
  <section style="background-color:blue"></section>
</div>
```

Source:https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp

Comment: @Yulianno problem, and for future questions, if an answer is helpful consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct